# Is it safe when set its own value in swift?

Tags: swift

I found a piece of code as following:

```
class Some {
  var p :OtherClass?

  func someMethod() {
    p = p ?? OtherClass()
    ...
  }
}
```

Is this safe? Is this good?

Answer (score 0):

The expression `p ?? OtherClass()` is equivalent to:

```
p != nil ? p! : OtherClass()
```

so the line `p = p ?? OtherClass()` is nearly the same as:

```
if p == nil {
    p = OtherClass()
}
```

So, it's safe. After the line `p` is guaranteed to have a non-nil value.

There may be a better way, so I cannot say it's good. But it is not bad.

Comment: it's weird: p = p!

Comment: @BollMose, have you not yet studied Swift Optionals? Or just feeling _ weird_?

Comment: I would do it as `let o = p ?? OtherClass()` as you noted. As, in this code, `o` becomes non-Optional, no need to guarantee it as non-Optional by yourself, Swift keeps it non-Optional. But for some developers who are accustomed to some other languages which have `??=` or `||=` operator, sort of equivalent to `p ||= OtherClass()` would be preferred. I would not say it is bad.